# How to find a unique word with regular expression from the log files in linux

Tags: linux, sh

I need to search the unique value of a strings from a log file like

```
tsetasjbvasgfsabggc Test: [ABC]
tsetasjbvasgfsabggc Test: [DEF]
```

How can I find the values Test: [ABC] and Test: [DEF]

Comment: perhaps you could just > grep?

Comment: regex: `Test: \[[\w]+\]`

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `cat "yourLogFile" | grep '\[...\]'`

For mutliple files use:

```
for f in $(ls | find *log* ); do cat $f| grep 'Test:\s\[.*\]';done
```

Just customize the `find *log*` part to find all of your log files.

Comment: I have multiple log files and need to find the unique values like Test: [<Any String>]. ANd I need to find all the string that contains a word Test: and after that there is []. And Square bracket can contains any value